# Committing moved files in Subversion

Tags: svn, slik

I moved a file from one directory to another but wanted to preserve the versioning history, using `SlikSVN`, the command line client:

> svn move old\dir\File.ext new\dir\File.ext

What I get when I run `svn status` is

```
D       old\dir\File.ext
        > moved to new\dir\File.ext
...
A  +    new\dir\File.ext
        > moved from old\dir\File.ext
```

When committing should I `svn ci` both the deleted and the new file location or just the new location and svn will know to make a move internally?

Answer (score 1):

- You **must**
- Committing *always from WC-root* (if all changes related to single logical action) is good bullet-proof policy